# NGINX force HTTPS except for some user agents on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I have a partial NGINX config file that gets pulled into a main NGINX config file automatically by AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have two instances running, one EC2 web server running PHP and another that's an SQS worker.

I had set up my config file to force HTTPS using:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

This worked great for forcing HTTPS, but I was running into issues with both the ELB health monitor failing due to a 301 (expected 200), and the SQS queue also failing due to returning a 301 -- the queue is triggered by a POST from a configured cron job, which seemed to not work with the 301 redirect:

```
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "schedule"
   url: "/worker/schedule"
   schedule: "* * * * *"
```

This is using [a package](https://github.com/dusterio/laravel-aws-worker) that listens for the POST request to that URL and then kicks off jobs.

To fix those issues, I tried this to check for the appropriate headers and turn off the redirect:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;

    set $redirect_to_https 0;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
        set $redirect_to_https 1;
    }

    if ($http_user_agent ~* '^ELB-HealthChecker\/.*$') {
        access_log off;
        set $redirect_to_https 0;
    }

    if ($http_user_agent ~* '^aws-sqsd\/.*$') {
        set $redirect_to_https 0;
    }

    if ($redirect_to_https = 1) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

This worked for the ELB health check (200), but the SQS worker is still failing, but now with a 404.

The only config that has working correctly on the SQS worker is a stripped down version (which I'm deploying manually right now specifically to the worker):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the successful POST request using the above config:

[image]

So the question is, how do I set up my config file to ignore the HTTPS 301 redirect for both the ELB health check and the SQS queue without having to deploy separate NGINX config files?

Comment: Look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/674900/nginx-if-statement-inside-location-returns-404/674901). "If" is evil and should be avoided, because it disrupt normal nginx behavior. Try [map](https://serverfault.com/questions/316541/check-several-user-agent-in-nginx) instead.

Comment: How would I use that in my case? It seems like I would end up with if's regardless of where I check for the UA.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic instance of the ["If is evil" NGINX scenario](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). There's a whole page dedicated to explaining how and why using if directives inside the location block can be problematic/give completely unexpected results.

I would recommend using NGINX [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for UA routing. Or if you must use the `if` inside location, at least replace `return 301` with `rewrite` as the latter is much more stable inside location blocks. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did previously have `rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;` instead of the 301, but various sites/articles said basically the opposite that you did about rewrite, so I changed it to the return. As for the `map` functionality, how would I use that in my case? It seems like I would end up with if's regardless of where I check for the UA.

Comment: Why do you consider `rewrite` safe in this case? Nginx page tells that only 100% safe things are `return` and `rewrite ... last`. In this case, `rewrite ... last` is not an option since 301 redirect is desired.

Answer (score 0):

One could use `map` as follows:

```
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $proto {
    default 1;
    "~^https$" 0;
}

map $http_user_agent $agent {
    default 1;
    "~*^ELB-HealthChecker\/.*$" 0;
    "~*^aws-sqsd\/.*$" 0;
}
```

The maps need to be defined in `http` level in configuration.

Then, in the `location`, one would have:

```
if ($proto$agent = "11") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri permanent;
}
```